# module installed with pip not found in pyhton -windows 10

Tags: python, module, modulenotfounderror

I'm using module pywhatkit but without any reason, today py display an error.
I tried to reinstall module and the system displays:

Requirement already satisfied

but when I try to import module, py reply:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywhatkit'

Any ideas?

Thank you
Angelo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you are using the correct env, if you are using an IDE like pycharm there is a good chance that you "choose" the wrong python. also if you are using pycharm you can go to FILE>SETTINGS>PROJECT>INTERPRETER to see packages that are available on the current project/add directly